# Get text with brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am using preg_match and regex to obtain information from a web page.

The page has the following pieces of text:

```
Choose platform: Xbox
Barcode (EAN) no: 0123456789
```

The first regex to obtain the platform works:

```
preg_match_all('#Choose Platform:.*?>([^<]+)</a>#is', $file, $platform);
```

However when trying to obtain the second piece of text I have having an issue:

```
preg_match_all('#<b>Barcode \\(\\EAN\\) No:</b>.*?>([^<]+)</a>#is', $file, $matches1);
```

I have tried to escape the brackets however having no luck? When escaping a bracket is it "\" or "//"?

Comment: Well, you have a typo in the regex. `Barcode` != `Bar code`. Also, no need to escape the `E`, and you seem to have some HTML in your regex that isn't in the sample text you gave.

Comment: @EdCottrell Sorry they are just typos, I Have not put the whole HTML as I don't think it will make a difference. My concern is how to escape the brackets?

Comment: `\ `, not `//`. But yes, the HTML absolutely makes a difference if you want us to help you solve the problem.

Comment: To match your example: `preg_match_all('#Barcode \(EAN\) no:([^<]+)#is', $file, $matches1);` See that it's just `\(EAN\)`

Comment: Since you delimited the string with single quotes, the engine sees `\\(` which means its looking for a literal escape followed by the start of capture group meta character.

Comment: @1nflktd I have just tried that however no luck.

Comment: @TheChosenOne How come ? See http://ideone.com/3KRApZ , as I said before, it's matching exactly the example you posted.

Comment: does my answer work? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the regex that I came up with:

```
$pattern = '#<b>Barcode \(EAN\) no:</b> .*?([^<]+)</a>#is';
```

using this, I got the following response

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Barcode (EAN) no: 0123456789
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0123456789
        )

)
```

So `$matches1[1][0]` containes the barcode :D

Hope this helps!